# SCRIPT438 error yadcf

Tags: yadcf

I'm just testing `yadcf` but I keep getting `SCRIPT438 error` in **IE** `(in ff it is TypeError: $(...).DataTable(...).yadcf is not a function`)

and I'm quite sure my libraries are on the right place, I can browse them using developer tools

What am I doing wrong ?

using version `0.9.2`

this is my example:

```html
<html>
<head>
<LINK href="DataTables-1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<LINK href="yadcf-0.9.2/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<SCRIPT SRC=jquery-1.11.3.min.js TYPE=text/javascript></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT SRC=DataTables-1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js TYPE=text/javascript></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT SRC=yadcf-0.9.2/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js TYPE=text/javascript></SCRIPT>


    <script>
 $(document).ready( function () {
 // alert("press format data");

      $('#ResTbl').DataTable({
 "columnDefs": [
       
            {
                "targets": [ 0 ],
              //  "visible": false,
     "orderable": false ,
                "searchable": false
            } 
   ]
 
 }).yadcf( [
 {column_number : 2, filter_type: "range_number_slider"} ,
    //  {column_number : 0, data: ["MOD", "CON"], filter_default_label: "..."}, 
      {column_number: 1, filter_type: "auto_complete",  text_data_delimiter: ","  }
]);

} );


</script>

</head>
<body>

<table id="ResTbl" class="compact">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 3 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 3 Data 2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 4 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 4 Data 2</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 5 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 5 Data 2</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 6 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 6 Data 2</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 7 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 7 Data 2</td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 8 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 8 Data 2</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 9 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 9 Data 2</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 10 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 10 Data 2</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 11 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 11 Data 2</td>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 12 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 12 Data 2</td>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>

  
    </tbody>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

What am i doin wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using new Datatables api with old yadcf api

From the showcase:

> note that this is the old yadcf API for init the filters  new init
>   function should be used when working with new Datatable (capital "D"
>   API) for new init function see: [DOM_Ajax_Multiple_1.10.html](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_Ajax_Multiple_1.10.html)

When you constructing the dataables using the "Capital letter D" it returns an object (which is not a jquery object) therefor you must use the `yadcf.init()` function to inityadcf upon it, like that:

```
var oTable = $('#example').DataTable();
yadcf.init(oTable, [{column_number: 0}]);
```

Anyway go over the docs (inside the yadcf js file) to learn about all yadcf goodies...

Comment: Thanks , i wasnt aware off the difference.

Is there any reason whe the "range_number_slider" and "auto_complete" are not working in my example ?

I just copied them from you example page.

yadcf.init(oTable, [{column_number: 0 }
  , {column_number: 2, filter_type: "range_number_slider"}
  ,{column_number: 1,filter_type: "auto_complete",text_data_delimiter: ","
 }]);

Comment: when using a filter that requires a third party plugin you must inlcude it in your html, those two filter types require you to add jquery ui auto complete and jquery ui slider...